# Run python script from a launch file not in the same directory

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts, cd

I would like to run a Python script by double-clicking a launch file, but the script is not in the same folder as the launch file.

The information is going to be recorded in a CD (kind of ridiculous, but this is mandatory in my university), and the structure of the files is like this:

```
MAIN FOLDER
|----CODIGO FUENTE
|--------scripts
|----INSTALADOR
|----MANUAL DE USUARIO
```

My launch file `ARDrone Autonomous Flight` is inside the folder `INSTALADOR`, and the script that I want to run is inside the folder `scripts`.

My launch file with `.desktop` extension had this parameter

```
Exec = sudo python3 /home/m/PycharmProjects/ROSAutonomousFlight/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_numeric_method_controller/scripts/ros_initial_interface.py
```

But now this information will be placed in a CD and I have no idea how to do it.

I have tried:

```
Exec = sudo python3 ../CODIGO\ FUENTE/scripts/ros_initial_interface.py
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try removing the accent on `CÓDIGO`?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I run the program using double-click, it does not work, but when I run that command directly in the console it works properly.

Comment: You will need to provide Sudo privileges to run that script. From the CLI you can enter the sudo password, but double-clicking will not work.

Comment: well I had added this command `Terminal=true` in the launch file, so I double-click a terminal is open, so I can enter the password, and it does, but after I enter the password nothing happens.

Comment: try `Exec=sudo python3 "$(dirname '%k')/../CÓDIGO FUENTE/scripts/ros_initial_interface.py"` - %k is replaced by the location of the desktop file.

Comment: @adonis, I have tried what you have suggested, but it did not work.